# how f() works in the given program in title to returning reference

Tags: c++

given program is a reference return type and i cannot understand it.Please explain the program line by line.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 double &f();
 double val = 100.0;
 int main()
 {
     double newval;
     cout << f(); 
     newval = f(); 
     cout << newval; 
     f() = 99.1; 
     cout << f(); 
     return 0;
 }
 double &f()
 {
     return val; 
 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a good book on C++ ? If so it should have a section on references. `f()` is just a function which returns a reference to a double - in this example it just returns a reference to the global variable `val`.

Comment: "given program is a reference return type" - and my human text parser just crashed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning,f( )is declared as returning
a reference to a double, and the global variable val is initialized to 100. Next, the
following statement displays the original value of val:

```
cout << f() << '\n'; // display val's value
```

When `f( )` is called, it returns a reference to val. Because `f( )` is declared as returning
a reference, the line

```
return val; // return reference to val
```

automatically returns a reference to `val`. This reference is then used by the `cout`
statement to display `val`’s value.
In the line

```
newval = f(); // assign value of val to newval
```

the reference to val returned by `f( )` is used to assign the value of `val` to `newval`.
The most interesting line in the program is shown here:

```
f() = 99.1; // change val's value
```

This statement causes the value of val to be changed to 99.1. Here is why: Since
`f( )` returns a reference to `val`, this reference becomes the target of the assignment
statement. Thus, the value of 99.1 is assigned to val indirectly, through the reference
to it returned by f( ).

Finally, in this line

```
cout << f() << '\n'; // display val's new value
```

the new value of val is displayed when a reference to val is returned by the call to
`f( )` inside the `cout` statement.

Comment: thanks very good explanation beyond expectation